# How to disable or hide the popup Exit fullscreen(F11) in chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

Every time the cursor touches the top a pop up appears in chrome

> "You have gone fullscreen Exit Fullscreen (F11)".

Is there any way to disable it or just do something so that it won't show on the top?

Comment: This might be possible only in the dev version ( canary ). I've changed the behavior of Ctrl+D, the bookmarking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/398945/disable-the-youve-gone-full-screen-notification-in-chrome

Comment: Please specify: do you mean A/ you want to do this on a web page for all your visitors or B/ just for you, on your Chrome installation ?

Comment: This is a security feature. If it could be disabled from within a web page, that would be a security hole.

Comment: If chrome *did* have this functionality, it would be a serious security flaw.

Comment: It is possible to achieve it by injecting assembly code into `chrome.dll` file. Please take a look at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1264349/how-to-completely-remove-press-f11-to-exit-full-screen-chromes-message).

Answer (score 4):

You can't, it is a browser feature.

Comment: You mean from the browser or from javascript ?

Comment: In which case the SuperUser question linked in your comment is a more appropriate place for this, as it would not be programming question.

Comment: Using javascript. I don't want this for my browser alone. Anywhere the page(a shooting game on HTML5) runs, so that the pop up doesnt interfere with it. User can exit using F11 but that popup shouldn't appear.

Comment: Well then I'm afraid you can't.

Comment: and I'm afraid you _shouldn't_. Don't change the browser behaviour for other users.

Comment: I suggest having a top margin on your game so that the user doesn't need to got in this area. Or use that real estate to display some information.

Comment: It is possible to achieve it by injecting assembly code into `chrome.dll` file. Please take a look at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1264349/how-to-completely-remove-press-f11-to-exit-full-screen-chromes-message).

Answer (score 1):

I replaced the browser. In Mozilla Firefox, hit <kbd>F11</kbd>. In the Full screen, drag your cursor to the top of the screen and right click.

MARK "Hide Toolbar" if you want only full screen. or else UNMARK "Hide Toolbar" as per what you want.

Comment: I think op wants a way to fix it in code so users of their site using Chrome don't get the popup. Describing a manual way for the user to stop it in Firefox probably isn't going to be of much help